# How do I combine a path with a string in batch?

Tags: batch-file, path

I want to have batch file that detects its current path and then combines its path with an "extension" to know the path to a file that is stored in sub-directory.

This is what I tried but failed:

```
SET mypath = %~dp0
SET newpath = %mypath% and \anotherFolder\MyProgram.exe
echo oLink.TargetPath = %newpath% >> %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: Best practice for assigning values to a variable; `SET "mypath=%~dp0"` So the second variable would be: `SET "newpath=%mypath%\anotherFolder\MyProgram.exe"`  Don't use spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example may assist you:

```sh
@Set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\LinkMaker-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
@Set "MYPATH=%~dp0anotherFolder"
@Set "MYEXE=MyProgram.exe"
@Set "MYLNK=test.lnk"
@(  Echo Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
    Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\%MYLNK%"^)
    link.Arguments = "1 2 3"
    link.Description = "test shortcut"
    link.HotKey = "CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+X"
    link.IconLocation = "%MYPATH%\%MYEXE%,1"
    link.TargetPath = "%MYPATH%\%MYEXE%"
    link.WindowStyle = 3
    link.WorkingDirectory = "%MYPATH%"
    link.Save) 1> "%SCRIPT%"
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%" && Del "%SCRIPT%"
```

*(I didn't create a separate variable for `%~dp0` as it isn't really necessary)*